# Content of html div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made an ajax call to a page and I receive some HTML code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    data: "id=1",
    cache: false,
    success: function(myHtml){
       //here I have myHtml 
    }
});
```

the returned html by test.php is myHtml and looks like:

```
<div id="firstDiv">
some text 123
</div>
<div id="firstDiv">
some text 456
</div>
```

How I get the content of firstDiv in jquery success ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jquery) to build a jQuery object based on that code.

```
var results = $(myHtml);
```

In this case, you will have several elements in the selection, so you'll need to filter them, perhaps with [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) in this case:

```
var firstResult = results.eq(0);
```

Note that there is no telling what jQuery will do with multiple instances of the same `id` in an HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(myHTML).filter("div:first").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$("#firstDiv").get().innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(myHtml).find("#firstDiv").html()
```